# Only connect to certain Wi-Fi networks

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, notifications

I have a Bionic and recently upgraded from Gingerbread to ICS. I used to have my home Wi-Fi and my work Wi-Fi networks saved in my phone, and I had it set to not look for any other networks. I never got notified about Wi-Fi networks being in range, it just connected to those two when it could.

Now that I'm on ICS I keep getting notifications about Wi-Fi networks being in range and the only way I've found to resolve that issue it to turn the wifi off completely. Problem is, then I forget to turn the wifi back on when I am at home or work.

So my questions are:

- Is there a setting to turn off the Wi-Fi notifications and I'm just looking right past it?
- Is there a way to set up my phone to only connect to a couple of Wi-Fi networks and to ignore the other ones unless I go in and tell it to connect to them?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to go into `Settings->Wifi` and then press the menu button to get to the "Advanced" menu, where you can then uncheck the "Network notification" option. This is the first option on the "Advanced Wi-Fi" settings page of my Galaxy Nexus, so a caveat here is that Motorola may have altered the settings menu.