# In which Android system file can I remove Wi-Fi password field?

Tags: root-access, file-system, system, user-interface, wpa-supplicant

If I would root my device based on Android (v4.0.4), which system file and how can I change to remove from the graphic interface the field where we manually type a password when connecting to new Wi-Fi hotspot?

ps. This is an additional and separate question to [Which Android system file(s) should I change to connect only to specific Wi-Fi hotspots](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215579/302598)

Comment: The GUI for new Wifi connections should be part of the settings app. Therefore there is not "just one file". Additionally the settings app is a system app signed with the system key (which you don't have). Therefore modifying the settings app is a complicated topic.

Comment: @Robert thanks! Maybe there is a solution with the `wpa_supplicant_scan` function?